# display all tables that start with specific characters

Tags: unix, informix

I want to show or search all the tables in the database that start with the name 'bar'. Is that something I can do through the command line?

I am using informix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select tabname from systables where tabname like "%bar%"
```

found it!

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is the query against the system catalog (as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401954/display-all-tables-that-start-with-specific-characters/10403230#10403230) by [user856753](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856753/user856753)).  If you want to be sure of working against all types of Informix database, then you'd probably use:

```
dbaccess dbname - <<'EOF'
SELECT TabName FROM informix.SysTables WHERE TabName LIKE 'bar%';
EOF
```

Note that the query in the other answer uses `LIKE '%bar%'` which matches table names that contain `bar` anywhere in the name, not just ones that start with `bar` (though it picks those up too).  The use of `informix.SysTables` ensures the query will work even if `dbname` (the database) happens to be a MODE ANSI database.  Without the owner name, the query would only work against a MODE ANSI database if run by user `informix`.

The main command line tool for querying the database that's distributed with Informix is `dbaccess`.  The first argument is the database name, and the second (`-`) is the name of a script (in this case, `-` means 'read standard input'), and the `<<'EOF'` notation is shell-speak for 'the standard input of this command is the set of lines up to the line containing just `EOF`.  The single quotes around the `'EOF'` mean "do not do any shell expansions on the material in the 'here-document' as the input is called.  If your script selects the database, you can use a `-` in place of the database name on the command line.  If you run `dbaccess` without options like that, then it runs in a curses-like interactive mode.

You'll get tabular output from `dbaccess` with this.  You can often improve the output using the 'OUTPUT' command:

```
dbaccess dbname - <<'EOF'
OUTPUT TO '/dev/null' WITHOUT HEADINGS
    SELECT TabName FROM informix.SysTables WHERE TabName LIKE 'bar%';
EOF
```